Window.open in TAB only if the window is not open
I'm using the following code to open a window if it doesn't exist, or focus it if it does.
The issue I have is this opens a popup window, not a new tab in the browser.
var targetWin = window.open('','winPop', 'sample-options');
    if(targetWin.location == 'about:blank'){
        //create new
        targetWin.location.href = thisURL
        targetWin.focus();
    } else {
        //give it focus (in case it got burried)
        targetWin.focus();
    } 

If I change this to use:
var targetWin = window.open('','_blank', 'sample-options');
It opens in a new tab, but then doesn't work as expected.
I want the TAB focused instead of refreshed when the link is clicked, even if the parent window has been closed, re-opened, or changed.
Any ideas how to do this ?
Thanks

I don't think JavaScript can control whether a new tab or window is opened.

@Barmar thanks. I can make it open a tab or window, but the above only works if a popup window it used. Looks like there is no way around this.
